# How can write physics in terms of local rest frame?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, accretion-disk

Many times I saw that people wrote that we write the equations in terms of local rest frame, for example in the paper of Novikov and Thorne that calculated stress-energy tensor for Kerr blackhole among others, and they got some result for shear stress and all quantities, but no where I could find how people in practice do it? For example in Schwarzschild case, it's easy that is mentioned in Carroll lecture, but have you ever seen somewhere for other cases?

Comment: “Novikov and Thorne ... calculated stress-energy tensor for Kerr blackhole.” Isn’t the stress-energy tensor of a Kerr black hole *zero* everywhere, except at the singularity?

Comment: Not when we have matter around, this paper is for construction accretion disk around Kerr BH, but my question is not relevant to that part. I mean shear stress $\sigma$ part, that in this coordinate only non-vanishing component is $\sigma_{r\phi}$. I want to calculate this myself.

Answer (score 0):

For this, we need to find the set of basis that they are orthogonal to each other and unit one. For example in polar coordinate we have $ds^2=dr^2+sin\theta d\theta^2$.
$|e_{\theta}|$ is not 1. we should divide it by $sin\theta$. Then we can introduce the new $e_\theta$ to be $1/sin\theta$ $e_{\theta}$ and so on.

Comment: Note that $sin$ is actually the product of three variables whereas $\sin$ (`$\sin$`) is the sine function.